# Define contract for possible empty array?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to define a CDC contract using Spring-Cloud-Contract like this:

```
org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {
    request {
        method 'GET'
        url $(client(~/\/categories\?publication=[a-zA-Z-_]+?/), server('/categories?publication=DMO'))
    }
    response {
        status 200
        headers {
            header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
        }
        body """\
            [{
                "code": "${value(client('DagKrant'), server(~/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/))}",
                "name": "${value(client('De Morgen Krant'), server(~/[a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]*/))}",
                "sections" : []
            },
            {
                "code": "${value(client('WeekendKrant'), server(~/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/))}",
                "name": "${value(client('De Morgen Weekend'), server(~/[a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]*/))}",
                "sections" : [
                    {
                    "id" : "${value(client('a984e824'), server(~/[0-9a-f]{8}/))}",
                    "name" : "${value(client('Binnenland'), server(~/[a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]*/))}"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        """
    }
}
```

In the generated tests, this results in the following assertions:

```
DocumentContext parsedJson = JsonPath.parse(response.getBody().asString());
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array().contains("code").matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array().array("sections").contains("id").matches("([0-9a-f]{8})?");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array().array("sections").contains("name").matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_\\- ]*");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array().contains("name").matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_\\- ]*");
```

But in my tests I want to allow that the sections array is empty, like the first example. Now, if my test implementation returns an empty sections array, the generated tests fail because it cannot find the sections' id for an empty array.

```
Parsed JSON [[{"code":"WeekendKrant","name":"De Morgen Weekend","sections":[]}]] 
doesn't match the JSON path [$[*].sections[*][?(@.id =~ /([0-9a-f]{8})?/)]]
```

I also tried with optional(), but the only difference is that the regex includes a '?' at the end. The JSON assertion still fails.

In the stubs, both results are returned, but for the test, I want the test to succeed for both, too. Are the test assertions purely generated on the last occurence of each attribute? Is there no possibility to have something like 'optional()' on the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't possible to do additional checks like this up till version 1.0.3.RELEASE. Since that version you can provide additional matchers - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.3.RELEASE/#_dynamic_properties_in_matchers_sections . You can match `byType` with additional check related to size.

Taken from the docs:

> Currently we support only JSON Path based matchers with the following matching possibilities. For stubMatchers:
>
> byEquality() - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to be equal to the provided value in the contract
>
> byRegex(…​) - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to match the regex
>
> byDate() - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to match the regex for ISO Date
>
> byTimestamp() - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to match the regex for ISO DateTime
>
> byTime() - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to match the regex for ISO Time
>
> For testMatchers:
>
> byEquality() - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to be equal to the provided value in the contract
>
> byRegex(…​) - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to match the regex
>
> byDate() - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to match the regex for ISO Date
>
> byTimestamp() - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to match the regex for ISO DateTime
>
> byTime() - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to match the regex for ISO Time
>
> byType() - the value taken from the response via the provided JSON Path needs to be of the same type as the type defined in the body of the response in the contract. byType can take a closure where you can set minOccurrence and maxOccurrence. That way you can assert on the size of the collection.

And example:

```
Contract contractDsl = Contract.make {
request {
    method 'GET'
    urlPath '/get'
    body([
            duck: 123,
            alpha: "abc",
            number: 123,
            aBoolean: true,
            date: "2017-01-01",
            dateTime: "2017-01-01T01:23:45",
            time: "01:02:34",
            valueWithoutAMatcher: "foo",
            valueWithTypeMatch: "string"
    ])
    stubMatchers {
        jsonPath('$.duck', byRegex("[0-9]{3}"))
        jsonPath('$.duck', byEquality())
        jsonPath('$.alpha', byRegex(onlyAlphaUnicode()))
        jsonPath('$.alpha', byEquality())
        jsonPath('$.number', byRegex(number()))
        jsonPath('$.aBoolean', byRegex(anyBoolean()))
        jsonPath('$.date', byDate())
        jsonPath('$.dateTime', byTimestamp())
        jsonPath('$.time', byTime())
    }
    headers {
        contentType(applicationJson())
    }
}
response {
    status 200
    body([
            duck: 123,
            alpha: "abc",
            number: 123,
            aBoolean: true,
            date: "2017-01-01",
            dateTime: "2017-01-01T01:23:45",
            time: "01:02:34",
            valueWithoutAMatcher: "foo",
            valueWithTypeMatch: "string",
            valueWithMin: [
                1,2,3
            ],
            valueWithMax: [
                1,2,3
            ],
            valueWithMinMax: [
                1,2,3
            ],
    ])
    testMatchers {
        // asserts the jsonpath value against manual regex
        jsonPath('$.duck', byRegex("[0-9]{3}"))
        // asserts the jsonpath value against the provided value
        jsonPath('$.duck', byEquality())
        // asserts the jsonpath value against some default regex
        jsonPath('$.alpha', byRegex(onlyAlphaUnicode()))
        jsonPath('$.alpha', byEquality())
        jsonPath('$.number', byRegex(number()))
        jsonPath('$.aBoolean', byRegex(anyBoolean()))
        // asserts vs inbuilt time related regex
        jsonPath('$.date', byDate())
        jsonPath('$.dateTime', byTimestamp())
        jsonPath('$.time', byTime())
        // asserts that the resulting type is the same as in response body
        jsonPath('$.valueWithTypeMatch', byType())
        jsonPath('$.valueWithMin', byType {
            // results in verification of size of array (min 1)
            minOccurrence(1)
        })
        jsonPath('$.valueWithMax', byType {
            // results in verification of size of array (max 3)
            maxOccurrence(3)
        })
        jsonPath('$.valueWithMinMax', byType {
            // results in verification of size of array (min 1 & max 3)
            minOccurrence(1)
            maxOccurrence(3)
        })
    }
    headers {
        contentType(applicationJson())
    }
}
}
```

and example of a generated test (part for asserting sizes)

```
assertThat((Object) parsedJson.read("$.valueWithMin")).isInstanceOf(java.util.List.class);
assertThat(parsedJson.read("$.valueWithMin", java.util.Collection.class).size()).isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);
assertThat((Object) parsedJson.read("$.valueWithMax")).isInstanceOf(java.util.List.class);
assertThat(parsedJson.read("$.valueWithMax", java.util.Collection.class).size()).isLessThanOrEqualTo(3);
assertThat((Object) parsedJson.read("$.valueWithMinMax")).isInstanceOf(java.util.List.class);
assertThat(parsedJson.read("$.valueWithMinMax", java.util.Collection.class).size()).isStrictlyBetween(1, 3);
```

Comment: One note though... If you pick the matchers option you have to manually match the whole block afterwards if you need to

Comment: Is there possibility to define an optional match of an array inside the body? In a case where I have customers and orders - an array of customers and each customer has an array with orders. The orders array can A) have items B) have 0 items (ergo - empty array). Is that possible to achieve with the Groovy DSL for contracts?

Comment: Nope, cause actually it doesn't make much sense. Create one contract that has the entry, and one that doesn't.

Comment: Very much appreciated! Thank you!